# The old Broadcom 43xx beast strikes again... 14.04 32bit

Tags: 14.04, broadcom, ubuntu-studio

I recently rescued a "bricked" intel Imac5 by installing Ubuntu Studio 14.04 32bit as the only OS. Apple techs swore the GPU was completely fried, but with Ubuntu the thing barely throws any heat and it runs fine (for my purposes). So I consider this a success story.

However, once I started messing with Broadcom drivers things started to get hairy. Additional Drivers supplied the `Broadcom-STA`, and after reboot the whole system was super slow and no networks were detected. Per forum suggestions I have purged `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installed `firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter` and had the exact same results.

Next I found a post that listed my hardware (bcm4321) requiring `linux-firmware-nonfree` to work in 14.04... again a slow system and no wireless detected.

I've tried each of these methods a few times adjusting the `blacklist.config` appropriately, and the results are always the same.

As a last resort I've taken the `ndiswrapper` approach. THIS does not slow my system, however no networks are detected and no wlan shows up in `iwconfig`. While the ndiswrapper GUI says that the driver detects the hardware.

I'm at a loss here and almost ready to buy a REALLY long ethernet cable. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be so grateful. I'm hoping I just overlooked something dumb?

lspci=

```
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:10 memory:c8200000-c8203fff memory:c8000000-c80fffff
```

iwconfig yields=
    `lo        no wireless extensions. eth0      no wireless extensions.`

This one is interesting rfkill list all just shows bluetooth=
    `0: hci0: Bluetooth     Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no`

---

UPDATE!
I ran some software updates as they became available... I have cycled through trying all of the available drivers once more. Unfortunately, I still have no wifi, but installing these drivers no longer slows down or locks up my system.

Comment: DO NOT add solved. Put the solution as an answer so others can see it and use it as well!

Answer (score 1):

After running the most recent updates I thought I would try another round of driver juggling. bcmwl-kernel-source worked, but wireless would be invisible after restart. I had the same results with firmware-b43-installer.

After restart I opened up a terminal and tried:

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

This started the wireless immediately. I can't say whether this would have worked for me prior to the most recent updates because the wireless never seemed to be recognized before. I made this change permanent as suggested in [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393936/broadcom-b43-driver-again-why-modprobe-b43-manually)

```
sudo -i 
echo b43  >>  /etc/modules 
exit
```

Works like a charm!